# How to subscribe to clipboard events in WinApi C#?

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, clipboard

I have set a viewer which is the current process and want to recive a message `WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD`.

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SetClipboardViewer(IntPtr hWndNewViewer);

var result = WinapiClipboard.SetClipboardViewer(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle);
```

It says [right here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms649025(v=vs.85).aspx) that i should use an-application defined function to parse that message. But it never hits the function/method.

```
    private static IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint message, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        var hdc = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;
        var clipboard = new WinClipboard();

        switch (message)
        {
            case WinapiClipboard.WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD:
                var result = clipboard.GetUnicodeTextAsync().Result;


                return IntPtr.Zero;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return WinapiClipboard.DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

How i should get this message? Am i even subscribing correctly?

**UPDATE:**

I'm not using WinForms/WPF or any of those .NET classic framework features. All i have is .net standard 2.0 or .net core.

Comment: [SetClipboardViewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649052.aspx) expects a **window** handle, not a **process** handle. If you don't have a window handle, create a [message-only window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#message_only) for the sole purpose of receiving clipboard messages.

Comment: This will only ever work on the kind of machine that also always has the full framework available.  That makes targeting .netcore/standard a pointless way to complicate your life.  Well, ours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all pretty straight foward from a winforms app

> **Note** : you cant do this from a console app (with any ease)

**Declare this**

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SetClipboardViewer(IntPtr hWndNewViewer);
```

**In your form constructor**

```
// this.handle is your forms handle
_ClipboardViewerNext = SetClipboardViewer(this.Handle);
```

You will then receive the `WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD` messages in your form by overriding WndProc

**In your form**

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    switch ((Win32.Msgs)m.Msg)
    {
        case Win32.Msgs.WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD:
        // Handle clipboard changed
        break;
        // ... 
   }

   // we call this so we to pass the message along
   base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

---

Another way to do this and maybe a more modern approach

**Declare this**

```
public const int WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE = 0x031D;
public static IntPtr HWND_MESSAGE = new IntPtr(-3);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool AddClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
```

**In your form constructor**

```
SetParent(Handle, HWND_MESSAGE);
AddClipboardFormatListener(Handle);
```

**In your form**

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
     if (m.Msg == WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE)
     {
        // handle message
     }
     base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

if you are using a class library you'll have to create an hidden from and pass back an action or event

```
private class HiddenForm : Form
{
    public HiddenForm()
    {
        SetParent(Handle, HWND_MESSAGE);
        AddClipboardFormatListener(Handle);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE)
        {
            // do stuff here like call event
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

> **Note** : None of this is tested however should get you started

---

**Update 1**

> `SetClipboardViewer` expects a window handle, not a process handle. If
>   you don't have a window handle, create a message-only window for the
>   sole purpose of receiving clipboard messages - thanks to **IInspectable**

**Update 2**

> This will only ever work on the kind of machine that also always has
>   the full framework available. - thanks to **Hans Passant**

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem - I'm not using a winforms project, that's a standard 2.0 class library.

Comment: hm yeah. that should work. but can't i do that without any forms whatsoever?

Comment: @DThr. im not sure of a way to do this, and maybe a lot more complex

Comment: so far no luck getting this message. for some reason i can't get the message, eventho i changed the clipboard data via winapi still no luck. @Saruman

Comment: @DThr. maybe worth unexecpting the answer, and expand on the question to include the ways you have tried in a minimalist fashion. that will open it up to people again to look at

Comment: An answer should - at the *very* least - explain, what the issue is. This one doesn't.

Comment: @IInspectable yeah this question evolved, and there was no answer. i agree it probably should be reopened as i'm not sure how to solve his problem. edit. oh it has been

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing a winforms project override the existing Control.WndProc rather than provide a static.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
if(WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD == msg.Msg)
{ ... }
else
  base.WndProc(ref msg);
}
```

Comment: I'm not using a winforms projects. that's a standard 2.0 class library.